# Why can't I close a sheet view when in landscape?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-sheet

When I create a `.sheet` view and turn the iPhone to landscape, I can't close it.

I tried swiping down from the top but the sheet is just stuck there.

Example code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var sheet = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Open da sheeeet") {
                sheet = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheet) {
            Text("you are stuck now ahahahhahah\n(if youre in landscape)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Any help Appreciated!

iOS 16.4, XCode 14.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the sheet doesn't automatically adapt to landscape mode. So,  you need to add a close button on custom sheet.
like :

```
struct CustomSheetView: View {
    @State private var isSheetPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Sheet") {
            isSheetPresented = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented) {
            SheetView(isSheetPresented: $isSheetPresented)
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @Binding var isSheetPresented: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("you are stuck now ahahahhahah\n(if youre in landscape)")
            Button("Close") {
                isSheetPresented = false
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.white)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In compact height environments (e.g. landscape iPhone), sheets adapt to full screen presentations and cannot be swiped. This happens in SwiftUI and UIKit and has been standard behaviour since sheet presentations were added in iOS 13. You will need to include a navigation bar with a dismiss button to handle this case, or your own close button within the sheet contents.